# Axis labels disappeared in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can anyone spot why I cannot see axis tickmarks on this graph I made in ggplot2?

[image]

```
(
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=daysincubated4, y=emission_mean))+
  labs(color = "", size= "") +
  labs(x = "Incubation time (days)", y = "Production (nmol g-1 dw soil h-1)") +
  facet_wrap(vars(compound), scales = "free_y") +
  geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 3, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
            fill="lightblue3",alpha = 1.0)+
  geom_rect(xmin = 3, xmax = 69, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
            fill = "lightcoral", alpha = 1.0) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
            fill="lightyellow2",alpha = 1.0) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = -2, xmax = 3, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                fill="lightblue3"),alpha = 1.0)+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 3, xmax = 69, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                fill = "lightcoral"), alpha = 1.0) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                fill="lightyellow2"),alpha = 1.0)+
  geom_pointrange(aes(x = daysincubated4, y = emission_mean, ymin = emission_mean, ymax = emission_mean + se, 
                      color = category, shape = category, group = category, size=category))      +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), 
                     values = c("dark", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(17, 19))+
  scale_size_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(0.7, 0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", labels = c("Thaw", "Anoxic","Oxic"), values = c("lightblue3", "lightcoral","lightyellow2"))+
  tidytext::scale_x_reordered(expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))+
  theme_bw()
)

df <- structure(list(compound = c("Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetone", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone"), daysincubated4 = c(33, 
95, 33, 95, 33, 95, 33, 95, 4, 10, 17, 24, 66, 4, 10, 17, 24, 
66, 81, 94, 116, 81, 94, 116, 0, 0), emission_mean = c(24.5, 
0.4, 35.8, 2.8, 24.5, 0.4, 35.8, 2.8, 59.1, 45, 11.4, 6.7, 0.1, 
46.7, 44, 56.7, 29.1, 2.7, 0, 0.5, 0.6, 7.7, 0.4, 0.2, 26.1, 
28.5), se = c(11.6, 0.2, 9.4, 2.5, 11.6, 0.2, 9.4, 2.5, 11, 11.4, 
4.3, 3.5, 0, 9, 9.9, 22.8, 13.8, 1.2, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 6.4, 0.1, 
0.1, 5.9, 7.4), sampling_period = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Thaw", "Anoxic", "Oxic"), class = "factor"), 
    category = c("mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
    "mean", "mean", "single", "single", "single", "single", "single", 
    "single", "single", "single", "single", "single", "single", 
    "single", "single", "single", "single", "single", "single", 
    "single")), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does removing the  `tidytext::scale_x_reordered(expand = c(0,0))+ scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))` get you what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recover your y-axis ticks when you change to `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` because its a continuous scale. The x-axis ticks disappear because of `tidytext::scale_x_reordered(expand = c(0,0))` which is normally used in combination `reorder_within` for factors but it seems to me like your scale is continuous here as well.

```
df%>%
    ggplot(aes(x=daysincubated4, y=emission_mean))+
    #labs(color = "", size= "") +
    labs(x = "Incubation time (days)", y = "Production (nmol g-1 dw soil h-1)") +
    facet_wrap(vars(compound), scales = "free_y") +
    geom_rect(xmin = -2, xmax = 3, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
              fill="lightblue3",alpha = 1.0)+
    geom_rect(xmin = 3, xmax = 69, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
              fill = "lightcoral", alpha = 1.0) +
    geom_rect(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
              fill="lightyellow2",alpha = 1.0) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = -2, xmax = 3, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                  fill="lightblue3"),alpha = 1.0)+
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 3, xmax = 69, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                  fill = "lightcoral"), alpha = 1.0) +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = 69, xmax = 120, ymin = 0, ymax = 80,
                  fill="lightyellow2"),alpha = 1.0)+
    geom_pointrange(aes(x = daysincubated4, y = emission_mean, ymin = emission_mean, ymax = emission_mean + se, 
                        color = category, shape = category, group = category, size=category))      +
    scale_color_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean",   "Emission"), 
                       values = c("dark", "black")) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(17, 19))+
    scale_size_manual(name = "", labels = c("Period Mean", "Emission"), values = c(0.7, 0.5))+
    scale_fill_manual(name = "", labels = c("Thaw", "Anoxic","Oxic"), values = c("lightblue3", "lightcoral","lightyellow2"))+
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
    theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

To everyone who struggles with missing discrete data, e.g. Study ID's in a forest plot: the function scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) brings them back!